# How to create and update with the same form

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I use the repositoryFactory in a custom plugin's Vue file in Shopware 6. When I save an entity I do this:

```
this.settingsRepository
    .save(this.setting, Shopware.Context.api)
    .then((result) => {
```

In case the person sends the form and this function is called, I want to get back the id of the setting in case the person hit's the save button again. But then the entity needs to be updated and not created. As I see from the response, there is an id, but it's in config.data -> json serialised.

How's the default way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice would be to re-fetch the entity after persisting it. This is because some entities may have fields that get automatically computed or indexed server-side and you'd probably always want to have the entity in its actual current state. If you're absolutely sure you don't want to fetch the entity again, you could manually set the `_isNew` flag to `false` after persisting:

```js
this.setting._isNew = false;
```

This will then cause the save function to use the update instead of the create route. Keep in mind that this is actually kind of an internal property, as there is no setter for it and as already mentioned fetching the entity again is encouraged.

Also you shouldn't have to worry about the `id`. It should've already been generated client-side and set to the entity, when using the repository to create a new entity like that:

```js
this.setting = this.settingsRepository.create();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. How can I fetch it again, when I do not have the id? Or do you use it like this then: repository->get(this.setting.id) after it has been saved?

Comment: I just tried it, I have the id already in this.setting.id. Thanks! One other question, is it most likely to set the default values of the entity once I have created it? Or how do you handle the defaults of the entity?

Comment: If a field has a default value it should be set on a database level when persisting the entity. This is another reason why you want to another reason you should fetch an entity after persisting, so you get it back with all the default being set.